Only expressions are allowed in this context
//... Part of @Composable code...
var line = ""

while ((line = inUri02.readLine()) != null) {
            //....
}

//the while loop is giving Only expressions are allowed in this context.

You can not set value inside while() compare part. Set it inside body.

Could you help me with that please?
